# Is there a way to delete devices from pubnub app?

Tags: pubnub

I am hitting 100 devices limit on PubNub's free plan, but most of those devices are not active. So can I somehow remove them ?

Comment: well, you could be right. Anyway we updated to paid plan, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Moved my comments to a formal answer. Please add comments to the answer if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Daily Active Devices

They are not removable because it is a running count of unique devices per day. The next day, the count starts over. It is likely this is either a mobile app with frequently changing IPs (on the road, like ride share, taxi dispatch, etc) or you are using a host like Heroku or Google App Engine where each execution of PubNub operation (probably a publish), the server host is creating a new dynamic IP address.

If you are using GAE or Heroku or other host/platform/cloud that uses dynamic IPs when it creates a process, then you will continue to see higher than actual IPs (daily active devices). You will want to implement UUID reuse. The new pricing is based on UUIDs now anyways but PubNub will generate a new UUID with every PubNub init so you need to persist a UUID and reuse it (set the UUID on the PubNub instance) so it doesn't over count UUIDs.